# HTML - Change display order of entire tables on a page

Tags: html

I have a list of tables with various elements on a page. I want to have the display order of the various tables change randomly each time a page is loaded. Any ideas on how to do this? For reference, the code below shows the first two tables. Say I wanted to randomly change their display order - how would I do that?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="lender-logo" width="200" height="168x"><img src="http://www.texaspaceauthority.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/CleanFund_LOGO.jpg" alt="Clean Fund LLC" width="200" />
        </td>

        <td width="15px"></td>

        <td width="340px">
            <strong>Clean Fund LLC</strong>
            <span style="font-size: small;"><strong>Preferred Financing Range:</strong> $500K - $15M
    <strong>Types of Projects:</strong> Any
    <strong>Contact:</strong> <a href="mailto:joshua.kagan@cleanfund.com">Josh Kagan</a>
    <a href="http://www.cleanfund.com" target="_blank">www.cleanfund.com</a>
    </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<hr />

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="lender-logo" width="200" height="168x"><img src="http://www.texaspaceauthority.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Greenworks-Lending-Logo.jpg" alt="Greenworks Lending" width="200" />
        </td>

        <td width="15px"></td>

        <td width="340px">
            <strong>Greenworks Lending</strong>
            <span style="font-size: small;"><strong>Preferred Financing Range:</strong> $30K - $5M
    <strong>Types of Projects:</strong> Any Eligible Technologies and Properties
    <strong>Contact:</strong> <a href="mailto:azech@greenworkslending.com">azech@greenworkslending.com</a>
    <a href="http://www.greenworkslending.com" target="_blank">www.greenworkslending.com</a>
    </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you please indent your code properly?

Comment: Is that tabular data or a table used for layout?

Comment: You would need to use JavaScript. I highly reccomend you [learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/JavaScript) before jumping into jQuery as others say.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use javascript on that page? My suggestion would be to write a javascript function that selects the table elements and then appends them back to their parent element in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to do with jQuery.  You would need to use some JavaScript to accomplish this and jQuery is one option.  You need a language like JavaScript to do this type of dynamic content.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/shuffle-dom-elements/

Here is the code on the page in case it gets deleted, this was take from that page:

### $.fn.shuffle :

```
(function($){

    $.fn.shuffle = function() {

        var allElems = this.get(),
            getRandom = function(max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            },
            shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
                var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                    randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                allElems.splice(random, 1);
                return randEl;
           });

        this.each(function(i){
            $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
        });

        return $(shuffled);

    };

})(jQuery);
```

And the usage is as follows:

```
// Shuffle all list items within a list:
$('ul#list li').shuffle();

// Shuffle all DIVs within the document:
$('div').shuffle();

// Shuffle all <a>s and <em>s:
$('a,em').shuffle();
```

In your case, you would:

1. Include jQuery js file in your webpage
2. Save the code for  `$.fn.shuffle` and save in a js file, and in include that in your webpage
3. Include the javescript to call the shuffle: `$('table').shuffle();`